# Center, rotate, and zoom photo on a face

Tags: photo-editing, face-detection

I have multiple photos of my 2 year old daughter since she was born and Google photos / Picasa has done a good job tagging her face in all the photos. Is there a way that I can center each photo on her face, rotate it so that her eyes are level and then zoom so that the proportion is roughly the same? Thank you all for your tips!

Comment: Yeah, do it for each photo?

Comment: What tools do you want to use?

Comment: Do you mean automatically?

Answer (score 1):

There is a Gimp script for this: [ofn-layer-aligner](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-tools/files/scripts/ofn-layer-aligner.zip/download).

Basically you load the two images as layers, set two points on the reference layer (typically, the center of the pupils), two points on the adjusted layer (center of the pupils again), and the script shifts/rotates/scales the adjusted layer to make the two points on the adjusted layer overlap the two points on the reference.

(*) I admit the whole thing has a steep learning curve if you never used Gimp. But if you start editing photos, Gimp is very capable and won't cost you a penny. There is a also a script to merge the first face onto the second one.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your photos tagged in Picase then use the Picasa editing tools. These allows you to rotate / crop / change contrast etc. For more info see 
https://support.google.com/picasa/answer/156342?hl=en-GB

Comment: To my knowledge, Picasa no longer exists...

Comment: @bearmohawk. It certainly does! The software download is still around https://picasa.en.uptodown.com/windows However, the web based Picasa has gone. This has been replaced by Google photos https://photos.google.com/

Comment: Available from a download site perhaps, but that version of Picasa is from 2014. It's not supported by Google anymore.